# Html TAG in String.xml in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

How to use mandatory * symbol in EditText hint in XML layout.
 How to use mandatory * symbol in EditText hint in XML layout.

Comment: i have to use inside TextInputLayout

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're looking for something like-

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text="*"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

But if what you really want is * as a hint-

```
<EditText
    android:hint="*"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```